# How to prompt an error msg in Excel, if a cell is blank using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel as shown in the screenshot below screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lQF9.png)

now as per our formula, when the if condition is false, then i want it to show out as an excel error msg, to notify user that they have to enter a value for column2, while saving or when column1 has data.

I tried adding as Data Validation, not sure how to write the false condition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs1Em.png)

Comment: Data Validation??? Its on the Data tab, You can set it to diplay an error message popup via a custom formula.

Comment: You will have to write VBA's Workbook_BeforeSave for the former and use Data Validation for the latter.

Comment: I do not want macros.

Comment: @ScottCraner - how do i try in the DataValidation. what should i enter in the false condition? Can u tell me the formula value?

Comment: Data validation is not put in the formula, but the formula is put in the Data validation.  Google "How to use Data Validation Excel" and you will find many tutorials.

Comment: @ScottCraner, i have tried with Data Validation and attached screenshot( second link). Can you please take a look and let me know your suggestion.

Comment: The formula would only be the test `=D1<>""`  When it resolves as False it will fire the data validation.

Comment: Sorry, i didn understand. Should i enter only  = D1<>" " in formula under Data validation and it should work? I tried. It is not displaying Data Validation error.

Comment: Data validation only fire when the cell is changed, again this is not a teach me how to do something site.  Please google how to use data validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `Ignore blank` selected in the data validation dialog box.

Select a column/range and use the formula `=D1<>""` in data validation and uncheck the `Ignore Blank` checkbox.

There might be many blank cells in your sheet for which the error will not be fired. But if you enter the data in a cell and erase it completely, the error will pop up.